# which technique is used to call a javascript method from a php page?

Tags: javascript

This is a javascript function

```
function lena()
{
    alert("this is it");
}
```

this is a php code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/boom.js"></script>
<?php
    echo lena();
?>
```

but I am getting an error saying **"unexpected call to undefined function"**. So guys can you please help me to get free from this thing?

Comment: You do realize that PHP is server side and JavaScript is client side? JavaScript functions can not be called upon as if they were PHP functions.

Comment: From PHP side you can send the function source code to the browser that will then execute it in the page `onload()` event handler or right away with the `<script>lena()</script>`.

Comment: Ya i know that Infact  i have the knowledge of web but there are methods by which we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   <?php
     echo "<script>lena()</script>"
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/boom.js"></script>

<script>
<?php
    echo 'lena()';
?>
</script>
```